# [Gatsby][GraphQL]: running a query after retrieving filter parameters from another query

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

Quick background:

I've got a listings project with around 40 cities and 16 regions that I'm targeting. I'm programatically creating a search results page for each city:

```
example.com/london, example.com/paris etc...
```

Then, I need each city page to have a query to retrieve listings that are only related to that city.

As of now, I'm querying same listings on each search page and then in the component I'm filtering the results on the client. The problem with that solution is that I'm loading thousands of listings on each page with page-data.json that I don't need.

I don't expect the listings to exceed few thousands that's why I don't want to add apollo to query directly from the client. I'd like all pages to be ssr'd. Filtering of results and pagination will be done via component and filtering of the array of results once the page loads.

The way I imagined that was:

1. Run a query to retrieve list of cities
2. For each city retrieved run a actual page query with cityId as filter parameter. For performance purposes, I'd like that to happen in gatsby-node.js and not pass cityId to the pageContext and then run a pageQuery from the page.js (which for some reason I couldn't make that work either)

Here's my gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require('path')

function slugify(str) {
    str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // trim
    str = str.toLowerCase();

    // remove accents, swap ñ for n, etc
    var from = "ãàáäâąęẽèéëêćìíïîõòóöôùúüûñńçłśżź·/_,:;";
    var to   = "aaaaaaeeeeeeciiiiooooouuuunnclszz------";
    for (var i=0, l=from.length ; i<l ; i++) {
         str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
    }

    str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '') // remove invalid chars
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-') // collapse whitespace and replace by -
    .replace(/-+/g, '-'); // collapse dashes

    return str;
};



exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {

  const { createPage } = actions;

  const listingQueryResults = await graphql(`
    query {
      allDatoCmsListing {
        nodes {
          company {
            cities {
              cityName
              region {
                regionName
              }
            }
            companyName
            address
            logo {
              fixed(imgixParams: {w: "128", h: "128", fit: "fillmax"}) {
                src
              }
            }

            #Companywide Terms
            insurancePolicy
            otherInsuranceTerms
            pricePerKm
            minAge
            deposit
            bookingPhoneNumber
            displayPhoneNumber
            bookingEmail
          }
          featuredInCountry
          monthlyPrice
          listingTitle
          pricesIncludeVat
          id
          originalId
          featuredImage {
            fluid(imgixParams: {fit: "crop", w: "800", h: "600", crop: "focalpoint"}) {
              aspectRatio
              base64
              height
              sizes
              src
              srcSet
              tracedSVG
              width
            }
            originalId
          }
          gallery {
            fluid {
              width
              tracedSVG
              srcSet
              src
              sizes
              height
              base64
              aspectRatio
            }
          }
          featuredInCity
          featuredInRegion
          listingDescription
          make {
            makeName
          }
          spec
          seats
          topSpeed
          transmission {
            transmissionType
          }
          weekendLimit
          weekendNoDepositPrice
          weekendPrice
          weeklyLimit
          weeklyNoDepositPrice
          weeklyPrice
          acceleration
          collectionDropoff
          color {
            colorName
            colorValue
          }
          dailyLimit
          dailyNoDepositPrice
          dailyPrice
          doors
          engine {
            engineType
          }
          engineSize
          horsepower
          monthlyLimit
          monthlyNoDepositPrice
          noDepositPricingAvailable
          
          #Listing Terms
          applyCompanywideTerms
          insurancePolicy
          otherInsuranceTerms
          pricePerKm
          minAge
          deposit
          listingApproved
        }
      }
    }
  `);
  const listingTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/listing.js`);
  listingQueryResults.data.allDatoCmsListing.nodes.forEach(node => {
    createPage({
      path: `/oferta/${node.originalId}-${slugify(node.listingTitle)}`,
      component: listingTemplate,
      context: {
        listing: node
      }
    });
  });

  const queryResults = await graphql(`
    query {
      allDatoCmsCity {
        nodes {
          cityName
          cityCase
          id
        }
      }

      allDatoCmsRegion {
        nodes {
          regionName
          regionCase
          id
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  const searchTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/search.js`);
  queryResults.data.allDatoCmsCity.nodes.forEach(node => {
  
    createPage({
      path: `/${slugify(node.cityName)}`,
      component: searchTemplate,
      context: {
        search: node,
      }
    });
  });

  queryResults.data.allDatoCmsRegion.nodes.forEach(node => {
    createPage({
      path: `/${slugify(node.regionName)}`,
      component: searchTemplate,
      context: {
        search: node
      }
    })
  })

  const emptySearch = {
    cityName: null,
    regionName: null
  }

  createPage({
    path: `/cala-polska`,
    component: searchTemplate,
    context: {
      search: emptySearch
    }
  })
};
```

I guess the more precised question is:

1. What's the best way to achieve the above. That is to get all cities & regions
2. Loop through cities & regions and query each city & region separately as opposed to running the exact same query and getting results for all cities/regions on a specific city/region page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've spent some hours on this. And I found a solution that works wonders for me. Went from 5 page queries / second to hundreds. That's because I query only once for all cities, regions and listings.

Then I wrote a filter function that's just chain of

```
FilterResults = (arr, params) => (
   arr.filter(/* city filter / if filter is null -> return true and move to the next*/)
      .filter(/*region filter - same as city */)
)
```

That function returns array of listings.

We loop the city results as follows:

```
query.allDatoCmsCity.nodes.forEach(node => {

params = {
  city: node.id
}

results = FilterResults(query.allDatoCmsListing.nodes, params)

// Then our typical gatsby create page

createPage({
      path: `/${slugify(node.cityName)}`,
      component: searchTemplate,
      context: {
        search: node,
        listings: results
      }
    });
})
```

This makes us query only once for all listings instead of 56 times for all listings (because I was using a page query in the template, that would essentially be called on every createPage)

Not only is this cleaner code, it's also much more performant. Hope I helped someone as much as I did myself ;)